# List files that exist only on a given directory?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to list out the files which are only in directory `./a/b` or `./a/d`. Now I am explicitly specifying by using `(-d && $_ =~ "b") || (-d && $_ =~ "d")`. Is there any way I can put needed folders in an array?

```
use File::Find;

my $filename = "h*.txt";
print ("Now it's:", $filename);

find({
  wanted => \&wanted,
  preprocess => \&dir_preprocess,
}, './a');

sub dir_preprocess {
    my (@entries) = @_; 

    #my @tmparr=("d","b"); This isn't working

    if ( $File::Find::dir eq './a' ) { 
        @entries = grep { (-d && $_ =~ "b") || (-d && $_ =~ "d")  }@entries;
    }   
    return @entries;
}

my @mylist;

sub wanted{
    if($_ =~ $filename) {
    push(@mylist, $_);
    }
}           

print ("It's:", @mylist);
```

Comment: Can you show us what @entries array contains?

Comment: Yeah I need files only from a/b and a/d

Comment: `$_ =~ "b"` tests whether the string contains a `b`, not whether it is equal to `b`. To do that, you need `$_ eq 'b'`. The `=~` operator treats its right-hand argument as a regular-expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `|` as "or" in a regex expression. `(-d && $_ =~ /(b|d)/)` would match either b or d. You could put the names in an array and then use `join` to generate the regex you need.

You might want to do things like prepend the path upto that depth, else you might get at different levels of the heirarchy. Also you can add `$` at the end to indicate that it comes at the end.

Comment: @karate_kid you can put the folders in an array and use join `("|", @the_array)` to get the regex you need. More info on join [here](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/perljoin.htm)

Comment: Hi, I tried to do that. But now it's not giving me correct result.

Comment: Now I am trying "a|b[0-9]+".. So it's working fine, but it's also pushing folder name 'b123' in list, which it shouldn't.

Comment: thats because `[0-9]+` matches 123, what do you want that to do exactly?